# i am trying to make a array of a object in php

Tags: php, arrays, class, object

I'm trying to make an array of `Spell`s.

My current code

```
class Spell
{
    public $bomb = 0;
    public $fire = 0;

    function Spell()
    {
        $this->bomb =0;
        $this->fire =0;
    }
}
```

And I declare the object spell on my game class like this

```
class game
{  
    public $Spell=array();

    function Game()
    {
         $this->Spell[0] = new Spell(); 
    }

    function s()
    {
        $this->Spell[1]->$bomb = $load($x)
            $this->Spell[1]->$fire = $load($x);
        $this->Spell[2]->$bomb = $load($y)
        $this->Spell[3]->$bomb = $load($z)
    }
}
```

It returns this error -- `Warning: Creating default object from empty value in...`
I guess this isn't the best way to create an array of objects. How to do it properly?

EDIT:
x y z, just return strings

Comment: First of all, making Spell[0] object, doesn't make the other keys objects too, so Spell[1] does not exist. Second, creating the object in Game() doesn't make it present in s() unless Game() is called there. And last for now, no info how $load is declare, it seems to be a function assigned to variable, but it seems it's not here, also $x,, $y and $z are not present

Comment: the function `Game` is the constructor, but the class is `game` (note lowercase g) so that probably wont work.

Comment: Also calling a property from an object, does not need the $ sign. for $bomb and $fire in $this->Spell[]->bomb must not have `$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have not created objects for $this->Spell[1], $this->Spell[2] and $this->Spell[3]. If you change your Game() constructor to this:

```
function Game()
{
  for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
     $this->Spell[$i] = new Spell(); 
  }      
}
```

It should probably work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have more than just one problems in your code.
However, I will discuss the one you have asked the question for.
Instead of

```
$this->Spell[1]->$bomb = something;
```

Use

```
$this->Spell[1]->bomb = something;
```

Second, What do you intend to do by using $load($y)?

If you're using a function named "load", use load($y)

Answer (score 0):

you must create object, then use it, look:

```
class Spell
{
    public $bomb = 0;
    public $fire = 0;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->bomb =0;
        $this->fire =0;
    }
}


class game
{
    public $Spell=array();

    function s()
    {
        $this->Spell[1] = new Spell();
        $this->Spell[1]->bomb = 0 ; //or other value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class Spell
{
 public $bomb = 0;
 public $fire = 0;

 function Spell()
 {
   $this->bomb =0;
   $this->fire =0;
 }
```

}

```
class game
{ 
 public $Spell=array();
 function Game($index)
 {
   $this->Spell[$index] = new Spell(); 
   echo 'constructer called';
 }

 function s()
 {
   $this->Spell[1]->bomb = $load($x);
   $this->Spell[1]->fire = $load($x);
   $this->Spell[2]->bomb = $load($y);
   $this->Spell[3]->bomb = $load($z);
 }
```

}

```
 $ob = new game(); 
 //$ob->Game(1); to pass the index for array.
```

?>

Comment: THe constructor should not be explicitly called, so the parameters should be passed through the instantiation

Comment: yup it should be some function like setIndex($index) instead of constructor function but I left it for sake of easy understanding, but yes that's not the best way to do it.

Comment: If you call setIndex($index) only once with i.e. `2` still `s()` will have undefined indexes. You need to call `setIndex()` for each index, which is not so different than hardcoding.

Comment: Can be initialized inside a loop if he knows exactly how much indexes he need. On doing this no need for explicit function, just putting inside  constructor will do the work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using lots of undefined stuff, I would say the half of your script is missing. 
I just added the comments down here:

```
class game
{  
public $Spell=array();

function Game()
{
     $this->Spell[0] = new Spell(); 
}

function s()
{
  /** 
    down here you are using these undefined "variables": 
      $bomb
      $load
      $x
      $y 
      $z
    undefined means, you are using a varible which was not declared. so it´s just null. 
    I tried to fix it: 
  **/
    $x = 1; 
    $y = 2; 
    $z = 3; 

    $this->Spell[1] = new Spell(); 
    $this->Spell[2] = new Spell(); 
    $this->Spell[3] = new Spell(); 

    $this->Spell[1]->bomb = load($x); // add ;  
    $this->Spell[1]->fire = load($x);
    $this->Spell[2]->bomb = load($y)
    $this->Spell[3]->bomb = load($z)
}
}
function load($v)
{
  return $v * 2; 
}
```

Comment: And you are using lots of hardcodded stuff :)